# Django model having two primary keys

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have two primary keys in a table i know django does not support multiple PK in same table 
i used unique_identifier but when i do syncdb all columns are not created

```
class SODIOrder(models.Model):
    sodi_order_num = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    sodi_order_version = models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    service_identifier = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    insert_timestamp = DateTimeUTCField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("sodi_order_num","sodi_order_version"))
```

`sodi_order_version` is not created can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

remove `primary_key=True` from your model fields and change `unique_together` as `tuple of tuples` like this:

```
class SODIOrder(models.Model):
    sodi_order_num = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sodi_order_version = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    service_identifier = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    insert_timestamp = DateTimeUTCField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("sodi_order_num","sodi_order_version"),)
```